# sftp/ftp need info on error messages

Tags: ftp, sftp, message

I need to populate a list of possible error's that could be encountered with `sftp` and `ftp`. After which I just need to match the error that comes with this list and do various actions.

In a properties file I have

```
SFTP_ERRORS= <list of comman separated token>
```

and later in java I just a do simple iteration over this  as

```
StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(getProperty(SFTP_ERRORS),",");
while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
  /// various action for specific errors
}
```

I am not able to find a complete list of error messages that `sftp` and `ftp` would give.

Also, some are logged on `stdout` and some on `stderr`, which is another thing to know.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: When you say "SFTP," are you talking about SSH File Transfer Protocol (which is unrelated to FTP)?  The protocols with "FTP" in the name can be confusing to talk about.

Comment: @hotshot I meant the Secure ftp. I believe it is other name for ssh file transfer protocol as this does involve setting of ssh keys between hosts.

Comment: The actual name is "SSH File Transfer Protocol," though many people use the phrase "Secure File Transfer Protocol" or "Secure FTP" to refer to it.  This gives the false impression that SFTP is simply FTP over SSH or SSL, whereas it's an entirely different protocol from FTP.  (There's also FTPS, which is FTP over SSL--but SFTP is often confused with FTPS, probably for the aforementioned reasons.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SFTP, [Page 20](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02) might be helpful. [JSCH](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) returns id and the message in the form of SftpException.